# Is it possible to use GPU backends with `Statevector.evolve`and `DensityMatrix.evolve` method?

Tags: qiskit

I find it useful to use the `Statevector.evolve`and `DensityMatrix.evolve` methods as a shorthand to using the Aer simulators with `save_state` objects inserted into the circuits, but this approach seems to remove access to the GPU acceleration that Aer can provide. Is there a way to set a GPU backend for the calculation of `Statevector.evolve`and `DensityMatrix.evolve`?

Answer (score 2):

In Qiskit Aer we have [`AerStatevector`](https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/aer/stubs/qiskit_aer.quantum_info.AerStatevector.html). It inherits `Statevector`. So, you can use it the same way you use `Statevector`. However, `AerStatevector` uses same runtime as `AerSimulator`, and you can configure it by passing the configuration options to `AerStatevector` constructor.

```
init_state = AerStatevector.from_label('+'*num_qubits)
psi = AerStatevector(init_state, device='GPU')
psi = psi.evolve(circuit)
psi.draw('latex')
```

Similarly, we have [`AerDensityMatrix`](https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/aer/stubs/qiskit_aer.quantum_info.AerDensityMatrix.html) which inherits `DensityMatrix`.

Comment: I tried this and the latest version of `qiskit-aer-gpu` I installed from pypi did not seem to have the `AerDensityMatrix` class. I tried it just with `qiskit-aer` and `AerDensityMatrix` is available there